# Need queue module to be shared between two applications

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to share some queue between two applications on same machine, one is Tornado which is going to occasionally add message to that queue and another is python script runs from cron which is going in every iteration add new messages. Can anyone suggest me module for this ?
(Can this be solved with redis usage, I avoid to use mysql for this purpose )

Comment: Are they running on the same machine?

Comment: @EricUrban Yes, I added now in question that info

Answer (score 0):

I would use redis with a list. You can push a element top, and rpop to remove from the tail.

See  [redis rpop](http://redis.io/commands/rpop)
and [redis lpushx](http://redis.io/commands/lpushx)

Answer (score 0):

The purest way I can think of to do this is with IPC. Python has very good support for IPC between two processes when one process spawns another, but not in your scenario. There are python modules for ipc such as `sysv_ipc` and `posix_ipc`. But if you are going to have your main application built in tornado, why not just have it listen on a `zeromq` socket for published messages.

Here is a link with more information. You want the Publisher-Subscriber model.

http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/eventloop.html#tornado-ioloop

Your cron job will start and publish messages a to `zeromq` socket. Your already running application will receive them as subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

Try [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) for hosting the queue independent of your applications, then access using [Pika](http://pika.readthedocs.org), which even comes with a Tornado adapter.  Just pick the appropriate model: queue/exchange/topic and protocol of the message you want (strings, json, xml, yaml) and you are set.